# Accessing Variables in another class and dividing NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, global-variables

Hy I have a problem accessing variables in another class.
Im making an app that makes note and let you study from the notes you make, for example the user makes a note that says *"Oceanic dolphins: are members of the cetacean..."*, and when the user press a button to study it appears something like this "what are *Oceanic Dolphins*" then the user press a button it appears something like this "they are *members of the cetacean...*" the problem I have is this When i enter the ViewController that makes the question it appears empty I think the problem lies on one of the next codes 
I make the Variable Globals like this

***QueRes.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface QueRes : NSObject

@property NSString *question;
@property NSString *response;


@end
```

***QueRes.m***

```
#import "QueRes.h"

@implementation QueRes

@end
```

I divide the NSString of the note like this

```
NSArray *card = [_argumentTextView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

QueRes *make = [[QueRes alloc] init];


if ([card count] >= 2)
{
    make.question = card [0];
    make.response = card [1];
}
```

the I apply the variable **question** and **response** in a ViewController like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    QueRes *make = [[QueRes alloc] init];
    _questionTextView.text = make.question;

}
```

then in other view controller i have the same code but apply with the **response** variable

Please help me I been stuck in this for weeks (I have ***Xcode 5*** and the app runs in ***IOS 7***)

(if you need more of the code of the program to help me fix it just tell me )

Answer (score 0):

You are making a new instance of a `QueRes` in your `viewDidLoad` method. Unless the `init` method of `QueRes` sets its `question` and `response` properties to something, they will be uninitialized, which is why you are not seeing anything in your text view: there is nothing to show.

Naming the `QueRes` instance you make in the third code block you posted `make` does not make it the same instance as the instance in the `viewDidLoad` method, and it is not a global variable at all. It is a separate instance of `QueRes`.